# Calling static class member

Tags: c#, class, member

I have the following code and cant figure out how to call the function (GetPageCount), which by way i found here.  I have tried more than several methods how ever none have worked.  Would appreciated some assistance with the line the calls the function and information on what i need to brush up on, i though I had preformed this previously. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {

        public static int GetPageCount(PrintDocument printDocument)
        {
            int count = 0;
            printDocument.PrintController = new PreviewPrintController();
            printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) => count++;
            printDocument.Print();
            return count;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testPrint = GetPageCount (@"c:\temp\test.msg");
            Console.WriteLine(testPrint);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're already calling `GetPageCount` from your `Main` method. But you're passing it a `String` instead of a `PrintDocument` object.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. You do not include the details on the specific error you are getting when you try to do it.

Comment: Your argument is incorrect. It is expecting a PrintDocument

Comment: What error are you getting?
Is it compiling?
It looks like your function GetPageCount accepts type PrintDocument
But you're giving it a string

Comment: I would  read up on some C# Basics Tutorial refreshers [C# Static Method and Variables](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/staticmethod-variables/)

Comment: So  i changed it to the following base on the feedback, not getting the desired results.   i am getting 1 where should get 12. PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
            printDocument.DocumentName = (@"C:\Temp\ImageIT\Source\test.msg");
            int testPrint = GetPageCount(printDocument);
            Console.WriteLine(testPrint);

Comment: The code above is going to print infinite empty pages. The `.PrintPage` event needs to set the properties of `e` such that printing terminates when there is nothing else to print.

Comment: I am voting to close because this question is about how to use a `PrintDocument` and not about how to call a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to pass a `string` to a method that is expecting a `PrintDocument` object.

I’d also check out the MSDN documentation on this, available here: [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.7.1#Definition)